# Plotting dictionary values in r

Tags: r, dictionary, plot

I have a piece of data which is a dictionary of key value pairs, in this form:

```
"1.354395": [
      87.4006653,
      92.0,
      84.0,
      2.18594456,
      6.58963251,
      1.97522652,
      33.8585548,
      2.89522839,
      0.0,
      0.3756774
    ],
    "1.355575": [
      84.21513,
      97.0,
      94.0,
      2.63353539,
      9.701308,
      1.48480618,
      24.1026344,
      5.00067139,
      0.0,
      0.476816237
    ],...
```

Here's how the data is in R:

```
list(`1.454552` = c(93.15171, 88, 91, 5.66755724, 6.469661, 2.06840134, 
40.66451, 2.44088984, 0, 0.401849449), `1.455795` = c(87.7752151, 
92, 87, 4.76685572, 2.86901379, 2.00754881, 8.92096, 4.836194, 
0, 0.0966028), `1.455984` = c(81.08724, 97, 94, 2.54499722, 6.61629057, 
2.2256844, 53.1162224, 2.008997, 0, 0.8071972), `1.456137` = c(85.67516, 
81, 97, 8.783263, 7.65513325, 1.53414989, 41.64623, 2.329053, 
0, 0.7988913), `1.456295` = c(88.17177, 94, 97, 6.011479, 7.758415, 
2.070262, 29.4543114, 4.043613, 0, 0.4748996), `1.456457` = c(87.75609, 
87, 89, 5.89587069, 9.498943, 1.66703343, 55.62601, 2.277172, 
0, 0.358969629), `1.456705` = c(99.99199, 96, 90, 5.10459852, 
9.459774, 1.52685452, 21.1448555, 5.652314, 0, 0.6192784), `1.456985` = c(96.77855, 
86, 80, 9.057593, 7.29362965, 1.44890714, 16.3208141, 5.47197628, 
0, 0.808024764)
```

The key is the time at which that list of values was added to the dictionary, and as such should be on the x axis, I then want to plot the each value in the list along the y axis with each value in the list being its own line graph. I have the data loaded into R but I'm quite new to R as a whole and I'm not too sure how to use `plot()` over a series of values.

Comment: can you post the data as you have it in R? You can use `dput(data)`

Comment: Will update the question now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ggplot()` for this. I hope I understood it correctly:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- list(`1.454552` = c(93.15171, 88, 91, 5.66755724, 6.469661, 2.06840134, 
                    40.66451, 2.44088984, 0, 0.401849449), `1.455795` = c(87.7752151, 
                                                                          92, 87, 4.76685572, 2.86901379, 2.00754881, 8.92096, 4.836194, 
                                                                          0, 0.0966028), `1.455984` = c(81.08724, 97, 94, 2.54499722, 6.61629057, 
                                                                                                        2.2256844, 53.1162224, 2.008997, 0, 0.8071972), `1.456137` = c(85.67516, 
                                                                                                                                                                       81, 97, 8.783263, 7.65513325, 1.53414989, 41.64623, 2.329053, 
                                                                                                                                                                       0, 0.7988913), `1.456295` = c(88.17177, 94, 97, 6.011479, 7.758415, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                     2.070262, 29.4543114, 4.043613, 0, 0.4748996), `1.456457` = c(87.75609, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   87, 89, 5.89587069, 9.498943, 1.66703343, 55.62601, 2.277172, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0, 0.358969629), `1.456705` = c(99.99199, 96, 90, 5.10459852, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   9.459774, 1.52685452, 21.1448555, 5.652314, 0, 0.6192784), `1.456985` = c(96.77855, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             86, 80, 9.057593, 7.29362965, 1.44890714, 16.3208141, 5.47197628, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0, 0.808024764))
data <- bind_rows(data) %>% mutate(group= row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -group, names_to = "time")

ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y=value, group=group)) +
  geom_line(aes(col=as.factor(group)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thats exactly it! Thanks so much!